# Display function in Circular Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having a problem with my Circular Linked list. I believe the problem is with my display function. Please let me know what is going wrong. The problem I have is that the first n-1 elements are displayed and then I get a segmentation fault(The last element doesn't get displayed and I get a segmentation fault).Thank you :-)

```
             #include<stdio.h>
             #include<stdlib.h>
             struct Node
             {
              int data;
              struct Node* link;
             };
             struct Node* last = NULL;
             void Insert_begin(int a)
             { 
               struct Node* temp;
               temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
               temp->data = a;    
               if (last == NULL)
                 last = temp;
               else
               {
                temp->link = last->link;
                last->link = temp;
               }
             }
             void Display()
             {   
               struct Node* temp;    
               if (last == NULL)
               {
                 printf("list is empty");
               }        
               temp = last->link;
               while(temp!=last)
               {
                 printf("%d\n",temp->data);
                 temp = temp->link;     
               }
               printf("%d\n",temp->data);   
             }  
             int main()
             {
              Insert_begin(0);               
              Insert_begin(1);
              Insert_begin(2);
              Insert_begin(3);
              Insert_begin(4);
              Display();
              return 0;
             }
```

Comment: 'Please let me know what is going wrong' : you are not doing any debugging.

Comment: Yeah! I need to learn to debug. Shall start doing it. Thanks

Comment: If you are interested there is still a full example of [**A Singularly Linked Circular Linked List**](http://pastebin.com/BirWtkvb) that may prove useful.

Comment: Yeah sure!Thanks David.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert the first element into the list, you must its link point to itself:

```
if (last == NULL) {
    last = temp;
    last->link = last;
} else ...
```

In your code, the link from the last element was uninitialised.

Comment: Hi Oehm! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ Sameer If u got the answer means Accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
        int data;
        struct Node* link;
};

struct Node* last = NULL;

void Insert_begin(int a)
{
        struct Node* temp;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp->data = a;

        if (last == NULL)
        {
                last = temp;
                temp->link=last;//you forget this
        }
        else
        {
                temp->link = last->link;
                last->link = temp;
                last=temp;
        }
}



void Display()
{

        struct Node* temp;

        if (last == NULL)
        {
                printf("list is empty");
                return;
        }

        temp = last->link;
        while(temp!=last)
        {
                printf("%d\n",temp->data);
                temp = temp->link;

        }
        printf("%d\n",temp->data);

}

int main()
{
        Insert_begin(0);

        Insert_begin(1);
        Insert_begin(2);
        Insert_begin(3);
        Insert_begin(4);
        Display();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi lucifer!Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is corrected code:
one mistake you have done that is at inserting first value you are not pointing the link to first node itself.In circular singly linked list if there is one node then link(next in general) field should be pointed to that node itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        struct Node* link;
    };

    struct Node* last = NULL;

    void Insert_begin(int a)
    { 
        struct Node* temp;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp->data = a;

        if (last == NULL)
        {
            last = temp;

          /*link field is pointing to that node
           *it self(you have forgotten this)*/
            last->link = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->link = last->link;
            last->link = temp;
        }
    }



    void Display()
    {

        struct Node* temp;

        if (last == NULL)
        {
            printf("list is empty");
        }

        temp = last->link;
        while(temp!=last)
        {
            printf("%d\n",temp->data);
            temp = temp->link;

        }
        printf("%d\n",temp->data);

    } 

    int main()
    {
        Insert_begin(0);

        Insert_begin(1);
        Insert_begin(2);
        Insert_begin(3);
        Insert_begin(4);
        Display();
        return 0;
    }
```

*

Comment: Hi Jay! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sameer_184:Would you increase my point by 1 for your help?and please accept my answer..

Comment: Perhaps if you provided more explanation instead of "Here's the fixed code" you would stand a better chance...

Comment: Hi Jay! I did upvote but because I am new in here.It doesn't show up. I need a minimum of 15 points or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
             if (last == NULL)
               {
                last = temp;
                **// adding this line 
                last->link = last;**
               }
```

That solve the problem

Comment: Hi Sohil! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with Insert_begin(int a) function,
When you are inserting first node, you are not linking his next to itself, so next time while inserting second/third/.. node, you trying to access first node as last->link but it gives you garbage value and that is reason

```
void Insert_begin(int a)
 { 
               struct Node* temp;
               temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
               temp->data = a;    
               if (last == NULL)
               {
                 last = temp;
                 last->link = last;
               }
               else
               {
                temp->link = last->link;
                last->link = temp;
                last = temp;
               }
 }

void Display()
  {   
               struct Node* temp;    
               if (last == NULL)
               {
                 printf("list is empty");
               }    
              else
               {    
                    temp = last->link;
                    while(temp!=last);
                    {
                           printf("%d\n",temp->data);
                           temp = temp->link;     
                    } 
                    printf("%d\n",temp->data); 
               }  
  }
  void main()
  {
      Insert_begin(10);
      Insert_begin(20);
      Insert_begin(30);
      Display();
    }
```